# Selecting 'long' versus 'long long' as 64-bit type under LP64/ILP64/LLP64 data models?

Tags: c, gcc, 64-bit, long-integer, long-long

I'm trying to understand the requirements for selecting a built-in 64-bit data type using either `long` or `long long`. I'm having trouble understanding the type equivalence and the alignment requirements of `long` versus `long long`.

What is the best practice or criteria when selecting `long` versus `long long` as a 64-bit type under LP64/ILP64/LLP64 data models?

---

Here are some related questions. They completely cover other topics, like `sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`, but they don't quite have a treatment of equivalence or alignment expectations. They also rely heavily on non-built-in types, like `uint64_t`.

- [The UNIX System - 64bit and Data Size Neutrality](http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html)
- [What's the difference between unsigned long/long/int in c/c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2550345)
- [Better to use long or long long in 64 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34601739)
- [Specifying 64-bit unsigned integer literals on 64-bit data models](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13158501)

---

The background information is code similar to the following to select a built-in 64-bit type to use:

```
#if _LP64 || __LP64__ || _ILP64 || __ILP64__
typedef my_u64 unsigned long;
#else
typedef my_u64 unsigned long long;
#endif
```

i686 and ARMv7 and below are fine with using `typedef my_u64 unsigned long long`.

***First problem case***

On a x86_64 (AMD64) machine, *if* `typedef my_u64 unsigned long` is in effect (due to `LP64`), then it results in a compile error:

```
$ gcc -mrdrnd test.cc -o test.exe
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:18:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘my_u64* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘long long unsigned int*’ [-fpermissive]
   _rdrand64_step(&val);
                      ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/x86intrin.h:46:0,
                 from test.cc:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/immintrin.h:166:1: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘int _rdrand64_step(long long unsigned int*)’
 _rdrand64_step (unsigned long long *__P)
 ^
```

***Second problem case***

On a Aarch64 (ARM64) machine, *if* `typedef my_u64 unsigned long long` is in effect (to fix the x86_64 error), then it results in a compile error:

```
$ gcc test.cc -o test.exe
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:21:16: error: invalid conversion from ‘my_u64* {aka long long unsigned int*}’ to ‘const uint64_t* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]
   vld1q_u64(val);
                ^
In file included from test.cc:4:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/arm_neon.h:17003:1: note: initializing argument 1 of ‘uint64x2_t vld1q_u64(const uint64_t*)’
 vld1q_u64 (const uint64_t *a)
 ^
```

---

```
$ cat test.cc
#if __x86_64__
#include <x86intrin.h>
#elif __aarch64__
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <arm_acle.h> 
#endif

#if _LP64 || __LP64__
typedef unsigned long my_u64;
#else
typedef unsigned long long my_u64;
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#if __x86_64__
  my_u64 val;
  _rdrand64_step(&val);
#elif __aarch64__
  my_u64 val[2];
  vld1q_u64(val);
#endif

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is why I hate using the primitive integer types. `<stdint.h>` FTW

Comment: @Mysticial - I know what you mean... I have wanted to change to `uint64_t` and friends for at least  5 or 10 years. There's a few non-technical barriers/requirements stopping me.